# Why is vector considered nothrow_move_constructible?

Tags: c++, c++11

The specification for vector's move constructor is (copied out of the standard):

```
vector(vector&&);
```

Notice the lack of `noexcept`. But both gcc 4.8 and Clang 3.2 report that `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<std::vector<int>>::value` returns true (i.e, 1):

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<std::vector<int>>::value << '\n';
}
```

What is the cause of this apparent discrepancy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard allows an implementation to strengthen the exception specification of a method as per

> #### 17.6.5.12 Restrictions on exception handling [res.on.exception.handling]
>
> <sup>4</sup> Destructor operations defined in the C++ standard library shall not throw exceptions. Every destructor in the C++ standard library shall behave as if it had a non-throwing exception specification. Any other functions defined in the C++ standard library that do not have an *exception-specification* may throw implementation-defined exceptions unless otherwise specified.<sup>191</sup> An implementation may strengthen this implicit *exception-specification* by adding an explicit one.<sup>192</sup>

Comment: In the case of gcc 4.8, I see that its `vector` move constructor is declared `noexcept`.

Comment: +1 And this strengthening can have a significant (positive) performance impact on `vector<vector<int>>::push_back`.  Said differently, the lack of the noexcept creates a significant performance penalty for cases like this.

Comment: Different compilers seem to be very different. Gcc 4.8 reports (via `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible`) that vector, list, string, set, multiset, map, and multimap are noexcpt. Clang 3.2 reports that all standard containers are noexcept. VS2013 reports that only string is noexcept.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe In the end it's an implementation detail, but as Howard mentioned it's quite important as it unlocks further optimization opportunities. It seems both GCC and Clang have done their homework :)